# Register FilesystemObject as safe for Scripting in IE8

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, filesystemobject

Is there a way I can make a FileSystemObject marked as safe for scripting? Right now I need to change my security settings to run ActiveX. But I need to run ActiveX without changing the security settings. I read about IObjectSafety but I do not understand it very well since I am new to this field. Hope you can help me guys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is designed to not work. ActiveX is a huge security hole so it must be accepted by the user before you can use it.

Using an activeX control gives you FULL access to a users computer.

And filesystemobjects are distictly not safe for scripting!

Comment: So it can't be used with IObjectSafety?

Comment: IObjectSafety is an interface that needs to be implemented by an ActiveX, its not implemented by FileSystemObject so you can't.  Perhaps if you give some background on the problem you are trying to solve there might be an alternative solution.